# Xamarin Forms UWP Hide Title Bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, titlebar

I was wondering if anyone knew how to hide the title (gray) bar of a Xamarin Forms Universal Windows Platform application?  I've seen some solutions for Android floating around, but I can't extrapolate an equivalent.

One of the Android solutions I've stumbled across: `RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);`

[image]

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run the App in FullScreen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

in the codebehind.

Comment: @AliSharabiani in my particular project, I put it in the xaml.cs of the views

Answer (score 0):

You can apply any of the following settings to your main view. The best place to set them is in **App.xaml.cs** just before the ***Window.Current.Activate()*** method.

Note: *The Full Screen Mode is different from a Maximized Window as it will hide the title and the Windows Taskbar*

---

To Start the App in **Full Screen Mode**

`ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;`

---

To switch to **Full Screen at Runtime**

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Note: *It returns a boolean indicating if it succeeded or not, so you may programmatically change your code behavior based on the result.*

Comment: Anubhav Ranjan, thanks for the attempt. I'm actually already running in full screen mode, yet the Title bar still persists.

Comment: I don't see the title bar appearing for me! Can you please share the sample?